# Find and replace variable in Ruby string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, replace

Let's say I have a string like so:

> "Lorem ipsum de color [post]57[/post]
>   sit amet [post]103[/post] desectator."

I want to find all occurrences of [post]*[/post] and replace it with the title of the post represented by the number. I'd end up with something like so:

> "Lorem ipsum de color Angry Turtle sit
>   amet Fuzzy Rabit desectator."

I'm guessing a regex will be needed... looking for what the regex would be and how to use.

Comment: By the way, if there's a syntax for my post id variables that would make this easier, that's totally cool too.

Comment: If your string really has only one level of one kind of markup, then you could parse it awkwardly (by rescanning) using a regex. But in general, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The gsub method on String has a handy block variation that works well here:

```
>> s = "Lorem ipsum de color [post]57[/post] sit amet [post]103[/post] desectator."
=> "Lorem ipsum de color [post]57[/post] sit amet [post]103[/post] desectator."

>> posts = {"57" => "Angry Turtle", "103" => "Fuzzy Rabit"}
=> {"57"=>"Angry Turtle", "103"=>"Fuzzy Rabit"}

>> s.gsub(/\[post\](\d+)\[\/post\]/) {|m| posts[$1] }
=> "Lorem ipsum de color Angry Turtle sit amet Fuzzy Rabit desectator."
```

Your syntax couldn't be much less regex friendly though. Try not to use brackets and slashes.

Comment: cool thanks... what kind of syntax would you recommend for such a thing?

Comment: Anything that doesn't need to be escaped in the regexp and does't occur elsewhere in your normal text is a good bet. Some template languages use curly braces { } or double curly braces {{ }}.

Answer (score 2):

(after reading your easier syntax comment)
If you have a hash like

```
posts = {57 => "Angry Turtle", 103 => "Fuzzy Rabit"}
```

or an array like, ehm,

```
posts = []
posts[57] = "Angry Turtle"
posts[103] = "Fuzzy Rabbit"
```

then why not go for string interpolation?

```
"Lorem ipsum de color #{posts[57]} sit amet #{posts[103]} desectator."
```

And you're ready to go.

Comment: Well my string is going to be input by a user. Plus my logic to get the post title won't be that direct.